# PHP Class and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am creating a class and I want to use a MySQL query in most of the classes, its a generic query that checks a certain row in the 'project' table when the customer logs in.

```
mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`username`,`email` FROM `project` WHERE `id`='{$_COOKIE['id']}'");
```

***That was just an example query I know it isn't secure.***

How could I do that without having to define it in every function in an optimized manner?

Sorry just having a brain fart since I haven't done PHP in a few months and have been using other languages.

Comment: It would seem that it may be useful info to put in a session once at login, not get from the database every time.

Comment: Missing double quote at the end of the query just to note..

Comment: Yeah the query was just an example, and thanks Joachim, that actually would work in this case, I didn't even think of that..although it does need to be quite secure I wouldn't want them changing the session variable.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated, you should think about moving on to [MySQLi](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Again, it was an example. I am using a database class MeekroDB to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the function you are using to do a query is unsafe and deprecated.
My advise would be to use PDO instead.

If you are using classes you could extend your classes with the class doing the database query. If the result of your query is static (as in : it will always be the same for that user) , I'd set a session instead.

Comment: Thanks I decided to go with a session. Just so you know I am not using that for a query handler, I use a framework called MeekroDB for my database useage.

Answer (score 0):

when user logs in use sessions

```
$_session['username'] = $row['username'] ;// this row is when you fetch query when user log in
```

then use

```
$_session['username']
```

every where in your pages.
 dont forget to start at top of pages

```
 session_start();
```